# HERE Geocoding API not returning 9 digit zip code for US Address

Tags: here-api

I'm using HERE maps Geocoding API for address normalization. Geocoding API always returning 5 digit zip code as response for US address and I'm looking for 9 digit zip codes. I couldn't find any related information in documentation.

Does HERE maps Geocoding API have this capability? If yes, how to achieve this?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example request?

Comment: it seems now they're providing 9 digit zip codes for everything?

Answer (score 0):

What about calls to

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=ADDRESS#########&apiKey=KEY#########
```

or

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=ADDRESS##########&additionaldata=IncludeZipAddOn,true&apiKey=KEY##########
```

I'm still just getting 5 digit zips back from there.